# How to use scheduleAt function in VEINS

Tags: omnet++

omnet++ has a function `scheduleAt()` to schedule an event after some time. this function is used to generate self message. How can I use it in VEINS. Likewise `handleMessage()` on omnet++ I want to generate a self message on a car to use its `onData()` function later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both functions just like you (probably) did way back in the Tic Toc tutorial. Just overload or amend the base functions for handling messages (and, if you overload a method, don't forget to call the base implementation of your superclass)